# Ошибка Access violation at address

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помечает эту строку

> s2 := p^;

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s,s1,i, s2, p2:Integer;
  p:^Integer;
  ret: Cardinal;
begin
  memo1.Clear;
  s:= StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
  s1:=  StrToInt(Edit2.Text);
  p:=VirtualAlloc(nil,4096,MEM_COMMIT,PAGE_READWRITE);
  if Toolhelp32ReadProcessMemory(s, Pointer(s1), p,  SizeOf(p), ret) then begin
  s2:=0;
  p2 := SizeOf(p);
  For i:=1 to 2 do  begin
    s2 := p^;
    memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(s2));
    Inc(p);
end; end; end;
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что надо исправить?
Заранее, спасибо помощь

Comment: p - действительный адрес? Не относящееся к исключению - что вы ожидаете от SizeOf(p) ?

Comment: sizeof(p) нужна для цикла, но щас не используется

Comment: Не уверен что проблема именно в этом, но: `Toolhelp32ReadProcessMemory(s, Pointer(s1), p,  SizeOf(p), ret)` - прочитает только 4 байта из памяти процесса, потому что `SizeOf(p)` - всегда равен 4(8) байтам для 32(64) битного приложения, а вовсе не 4096 байтам, которые вы выделяли выше. А дальше в цикле вы пытаетесь прочитать 8 байт (два раза по 4). При этом вызов `VirtualAlloc()` не выделяет память до первого обращения (записи?) к ней, отсюда, возможно, и происходит ошибка.